# Plotting tree diagrams

Tags: trees

I am trying to learn to plot tree diagrams. Particulary I am interested in the type of diagrams I drew.[image]

Here is the code I made so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \coordinate
    child [level distance=30mm]
    child [level distance=15mm]{
       {child [level distance=30mm] 
            {child [level distance=15mm] 
            child [level distance=30mm]}
       child [level distance=15mm]}
     };

     
     \begin{scope}[shift={(3,-3)}]
     \node (y1) {\textit{}};  
     \node  (y0)[right of=y1] {\textit{}};
     \path [->,auto, thick](y1) edge [] node [above]{$\chi_0$} (y0);
     \end{scope}
     
   \begin{scope}[shift={(6,0)}]
 \coordinate
    child [level distance=30mm]
    child [level distance=15mm]{
       {child [level distance=30mm] 
            {child [level distance=15mm] 
            child [level distance=30mm]}
       child [level distance=15mm]}
     };
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

There are 3 problems I encountered:

1. The child edges are not aligned with the parent edges.

<s>2) Unable to add a second tree to the same figure.</s>

<s>3) Unable to add an arrow and label it.</s>

I would appreciate if someone could help with my questions.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, I suggest for add the other tree use `scope` environment, inside the tikz code that you want. For label you can use `node`: `\node[right] at (2cm,-60mm) {draw arrow};` just after of the first tree.

Comment: Welcome! `forest` or a similar package is recommended.

Comment: You're loading it but not using it?

Comment: Hello. I was not able to make edges of different lenghts in the forest package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Forest, though this is largely a matter of personal preference. But using *some* tree-specific package or other will make things a lot easier. The following defines a style `nice tree` for the basic style. For combinations of two trees of the kind you want, we define `double nice trees` which is basically a `nice tree` with a `phantom` root node and a space between the two sub-trees for you to put an arrow or whatever.

```
  nice tree/.style={%
```

We define this separately so it can be easily applied to single trees rather than being limited to cases where we want a pair.

```
    before typesetting nodes={%
```

We delay this so the nodes exist when the style is applied.

```
      for tree={%
```

Then we apply the following to the current `tree` i.e. the current node and its descendants.

```
        circle,
        fill,
        inner sep=1.5pt,
```

Make our dot.

```
        parent anchor=center,
        child anchor=center,
```

Aim edges to and from dot's centre to avoid getting weird-looking twists above and below.

```
        calign=fixed edge angles,
```

We want the edges of parents and children to be at constant angles.

```
      },
    },
  },
```

`double nice trees` sets up a tree group (2+ trees) with a `phantom` root and applies `nice tree` to the `phantom`'s children.

```
  double nice trees/.style={%
    phantom,
    s sep'+=50pt,
    for children={nice tree},
  },
}
```

To align the dots as in the sketch, we use `tier=<name>`. We use four named tiers (`A`, `B`, `C` and `D`) to ensure correct alignment within and between the two trees.

We use `tikz+={}` to add the arrow between the two.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713845/
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\forestset{%
  nice tree/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        circle,
        fill,
        inner sep=1.5pt,
        parent anchor=center,
        child anchor=center,
        calign=fixed edge angles,
      },
    },
  },
  double nice trees/.style={%
    phantom,
    s sep'+=50pt,
    for children={nice tree},
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  double nice trees,
  tikz+={\draw [-Latex,thick,shorten >=15pt,shorten <=15pt] (!r122 |- !r211) -- node [above,midway] {$\chi_0$} (!r211); },
  [
    [
      [,tier=A]
      [
        [,tier=B
          [, tier=C
            [,phantom,tier=D]
          ]
          [,tier=D]
        ]
        [,tier=A
          [,phantom,tier=B]      
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [
      [
        [,tier=B]
        [,tier=A]
      ]
      [,tier=A
        [,tier=C]
        [,tier=B
          [,phantom,tier=C]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

A bug in Okular/KDE means my images are currently horrible quality, so the following will look fuzzy here even though the output is fine.

[image: double nice trees with arrow]

You can name nodes rather than using coordinates such as `(!r122)` if preferred. `!r122` just means the node you reach if you follow the path *root*-*first child*-*second child*-*second child*, but `name=fred` may be easier.

Answer (score 0):

May be you serve, using `forest` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}

\newcommand{\dotikz}{\tikz{\fill (0,0) circle (2pt);}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={s sep=20pt} % horizontal separation between nodes
    [\dotikz%first
        [,phantom] % phantom node to add space
        [\dotikz,l=2cm]
        [\dotikz
            [,phantom]
            [\dotikz,l=2cm
                [\dotikz]
                [,phantom]
                [\dotikz,l=2cm]
            ]
        [\dotikz]
        ]
    ]
    \end{forest}
\end{minipage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[-latex] (-2.5,0) -- (-.5,0) node[midway,below] {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={s sep=20pt}
        [\dotikz
            [\dotikz
                    [,phantom]
                    [\dotikz,l=2cm]
                    [\dotikz]
            ]
            [,phantom]
            [\dotikz,l=2cm
                [,phantom]
                [\dotikz,l=2cm]
                [\dotikz]
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Forest}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought the focus of the question was on aligning parent and child edges rather than using `forest` *per se* ....