Forest edge labeling
I am learing to plot forest diagrams.
I am in the process of ploting an implicit tree with n children.
There are 3 questions I could not resolve:
1) How to change the dotted edge to  ( . . . ) rather than (.........)? (I suspect "edge=dotted" has to be change.)
2) How to label a group of edges?
3)My code has an unknow error in the forest enviroment that autocorrects itself.
Ideally I need this picture: 
The final code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing}



\begin{document}



\begin{figure} 
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    coordinate, calign=fixed edge angles, calign angle=25, edge=thick,
    {}
}
[, name=n1
    [,l*=2]
    [
        [,l*=2]
        [,name=d1
            [,no edge]
            [,no edge,name=d2
                [,l*=2]
                [,name=n2
                    [,l*=2
                        []
                        [,l*=2]
                    ]
                    []
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\draw[black, thick, decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=4pt, raise=4pt}] (n1)--node[above right=5pt]{$n$ carets} (n2);
\path(d1)--node[sloped]{\Large\dots}(d2);
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    coordinate, calign=fixed edge angles, calign angle=25, edge=thick,
    {}
}
[, name=n1
    [,l*=2]
    [
        [,l*=2]
        [,name=d1
            [,no edge]
            [,no edge,name=d2
                [,l*=2]
                [,name=n2
                    [,l*=2                    ]
                    [
                        [,l*=2]
                        []
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\draw[black, thick, decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=4pt, raise=4pt}] (n1)--node[above right=5pt]{$n$ carets} (n2);
\path(d1)--node[sloped]{\Large\dots}(d2);
\end{forest}



    \caption{.}
    \label{fig:generator}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


What's the text of the error? What do you mean by 'label a group of edges'? If you found this code somewhere, please link. The site search is terrible and finding stuff often impossible.

The first error is caused by the blank lines. You can't leave blank lines inside forest trees. The second is caused by not loading the arrows.meta library.

Oh, it's mine. I can find it with grep. For anybody else: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713845/.

Note that you probably want to reduce s sep+=100pt here as your tree has a different shape.

A few suggestions:

Use the coordinate shape for nodes.
Instead of using tier, you can double the length of each left branch using l*=2.
You can name nodes and then use them with basic TikZ commands like \draw or \path.
The brace decoration is one way to label the group of edges.
The three dots can be made using \dots in a sloped node.


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    coordinate, calign=fixed edge angles, calign angle=25, edge=thick,
    if n=1{l*=2}{}
}
[, name=n1
    []
    [
        []
        [
            []
            [, name=d1
                [, no edge]
                [, no edge, l*=1.5, name=d2
                    []
                    [, name=n2
                        [
                            []
                            []
                        ]
                        []
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\draw[red, thick, decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=4pt, raise=4pt}] (n1)--node[above right=5pt]{$n$ carets} (n2);
\path(d1)--node[sloped]{\Large\dots}(d2);
\end{forest}

\end{document}


(+1) for if n=1{l*=2}{}. Definitely makes sense here (though not in the answer this question is based on).

triple dots turns the edge into three dots on an invisible line. I've also got rid of the dots at nodes you don't show but, since you didn't mention that, I've left comments explaining how to restore them.
triple dots also handles labelling the edges, since the two sets have exactly the same structure so far as this is concerned.
Finally, I've put back the bits you removed causing errors and removed the bits you put in causing other errors. Never leave an uncommented blank line inside a forest. Unlike a tikzpicture, a forest doesn't ignore these within the [...]. If you want to add blank lines after the final ], that will work. But the actual tree spec is read by a special parser and needs to find the right things in the expected places. It takes exception if it sees no end ] in sight.
Even though you don't want an arrow, you left an arrow in the code while removing the library it depends on. I've removed the code, since it isn't actually drawing anything.
Note that to help structure the tree, it may be best to comment out coordinate or circle, fill in for tree and to replace it with something like content/.option=level which will put the number of the level into the node. Your tier names are equivalent to level - 1, so you can use these to easily identify which nodes need to be tweaked or whether things need to be added or removed. Or you can say label/.option=level to turn the level number into a label instead. It will make a mess but makes it much easier to develop the tree. By putting it in the before typesetting nodes={before tree={}} you only have a single place to comment out or delete the code when you're done.
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714832/ addaswyd o ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713845/
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{%
  nice tree/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={% uncomment the next three lines and comment the following one for dots at nodes
%         circle,
%         fill,
%         inner sep=1.5pt,
        coordinate,
        parent anchor=center,
        child anchor=center,
        calign=fixed edge angles,
      },
    },
  },
  double nice trees/.style={%
    phantom,
    s sep'+=100pt,
    for children={nice tree},
  },
  triple dots/.style={%
    edge path'={(!parent.parent anchor) -- node[pos=0.25,my dot] {} node [pos=0.5,my dot] {} node [pos=0.75,my dot] {} (.child anchor)},
    edge+={draw=none},
    !u.label={[name=\foresteoption{name}-label]right:$n$ carets},
    !u.tikz+={%
      \draw [dotted] (\foresteoption{name}-label) edge  ([xshift=5pt]!uuu.east) -- ([xshift=5pt]!{last,last}.east) ;
    },
  },
  /tikz/my dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=0.75pt},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  double nice trees,
  [
    [,tier=0
      [,tier=2]
      [,tier=1
        [,tier=3]
        [,tier=2
          [,tier=4]
          [,tier=3
            [,phantom,tier=4
              [,phantom,tier=5]
            ]
            [,tier=5,triple dots
              [,tier=7]
              [,tier=6
                [,tier=8
                  [,tier=10]
                  [,tier=9
                    [,tier=10,phantom]
                  ]
                ]
                [,tier=7
                  [,tier=8,phantom]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [,tier=0
      [,tier=2]
      [,tier=1
        [,tier=3]
        [,tier=2
          [,tier=4]
          [,tier=3
            [,phantom]
            [,tier=5,triple dots
              [,tier=7]
              [,tier=6
                [,tier=8]
                [,tier=7
                  [,tier=9]
                  [,tier=8
                    [,tier=9,phantom]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

Okular has a bug which causes all my images to suck, so I present the above as a challenge to readers' imagination. It does, however, look rather like the tree in the OP's question. It is a bit more spaced out and the angles are slightly gentler, so it is a bit less skinny looking. (This could, obviously, be altered - this is just how it came out.)
